# How to approximate a square root of a float in javascript

Tags: math

I wanna to approximate the square root of this function. Math.sqrt(float);
The result should be another float which decimal positions after the point are maximum 6 or 7.
Using the standard Math.sqrt(float) I get a very big number like 0.343423409554534598959 which is too much for me.

Comment: So just round the result to an appropriate number of digits. This will be far faster than writing your own approximation, and less chance of introducing bugs.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to get a smaller and more managable number, you can use the `toFixed` method as so:

```
var x = 0.343423409554534598959;
console.log( x.toFixed(3) )
// outputs 0.343
```

If you can't bear the thought of calculating the whole square root and just throwing digits of precision away, you can use an approximation method. Be warned though, premature optimization is the root of all evil; and the KISS idiom goes against this.

Here's Heron's method:

```
function sqrt(num) {
  // Create an initial guess by simply dividing by 3.
  var lastGuess, guess = num / 3;

  // Loop until a good enough approximation is found.
  do {
    lastGuess = guess;  // store the previous guess

    // find a new guess by averaging the old one with
    // the original number divided by the old guess.
    guess = (num / guess + guess) / 2;

  // Loop again if the product isn't close enough to
  // the original number.
  } while(Math.abs(lastGuess - guess) > 5e-15);

  return guess;  // return the approximate square root
};
```

For more, it should be trivial to implement one from [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots).

Comment: This second sqrt function is not a sqrt function, but actually a rounding function.  This was very misleading to me at first until I walked through the code and realized it wasn't trying to calculate sqrt at all!  You might consider changing the name of the second method.

Comment: @AlexPritchard You're right! I removed the entire function as it was of no specific value here...

Answer (score 0):

browsing stackoverflow I found this code some time ago, that approxes to desired precision
(this code is not mine, I just ^C^V-ed)

```
function round (value, precision, mode)
{
    precision |= 0; // making sure precision is integer
    var m = Math.pow(10, precision);
    value *= m;
    var sgn = (value > 0) | - (value < 0); // sign of the number
    var isHalf = value % 1 === 0.5 * sgn;
    var f = Math.floor(value);

    if (isHalf)
        switch (mode) {
            case 'PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN':
                value = f + (sgn < 0); // rounds .5 toward zero
                break;
            case 'PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN':
                value = f + (f % 2 * sgn); // rouds .5 towards the next even integer
                break;
            case 'PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD':
                value = f + !(f % 2); // rounds .5 towards the next odd integer
                break;
            default:
                value = f + (sgn > 0); // rounds .5 away from zero
        }

    return (isHalf ? value : Math.round(value)) / m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can round square root by using

```
(double)Math.round(float * Math.pow(10,r)) /Math.pow(10,r);
```

where, `r` is numbers we want to print after dot.

**Try program like this**

```
    float f = 0.123f;   
    double d = Math.sqrt(f);
    d = (double)Math.round(d * Math.pow(10,5)) /Math.pow(10,5); 
    System.out.println(d);
```

Output :  0.35071